# Pascal (Script) and exception control flow

Tags: exception, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I'm working with a PascalScript innosetup installer, and I fail to see where the control of the following block is flowing.

```
function Foo(): String;
begin
  Result := 'foo';
  RaiseException('...');
end;

procedure Test();
var
  Z : String;
begin
  Z := '';
  try
    Z := Foo();
  except
    Log(Z);
  end
end;
```

My installer seems to indicate `Z` is being set with the `Result` of the `Foo` function.  My understanding of exceptions in 'most' programming languages tells me the assignment `Z := Foo()` should not happen in case of exception.

When the `Foo` function raises, should `Z` still be assigned to?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: you're right.  I hand-mixed example and production code.  I made it compile and run.

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi, strings as result values are treated like `var` parameters. In other words, a function like Foo is in fact compiled as:

```
procedure Foo(var Result: string);
begin
  Result := 'Foo';
  RaiseException(...);
end;
```

This means that `Z` (through the reference parameter) is assigned the value `'Foo'` immediately, i.e. **before** the exception is raised.

In other words, the function result is not just kept in a local variable called `Result` and then returned when the function ends -- which would be prevented by the exception -- it is assigned immediately.

I assume this is exactly what happens in PascalScript as well.

Comment: So the function 'knows' what's going to happen to its return value?  Then how does the function call differentiate between `A := Foo()` and `A := '...' + Foo()`?

Comment: @xtofl: Because for `'...' + Foo()` it writes to an intermediate string which is not reachable. I'm sure that intermediate string is set to `'Foo'`, but the exception hinders the formation of the full expression. IOW, it does: `intermediate := Foo();` followed by `A := '...' + intermediate;`. `intermediate`is set to `'Foo'` before the exception, but the full expression can not continue to be formed, because that is after the exception. And `intermediate` is not reachable, i.e. it is not explicitly referenced in the code.

Comment: So in the `A := Foo()` case there is no intermediate string - is that an optimization or is it defined in the language?

Comment: There is no reason for the compiler to allocate and initialize an intermediate, because the single call is not a composite expression.

Comment: I don't understand that: the simplest way would be to always have a temporary implicit `Result` variable, and assign it in case 1, or concatenate it in case 2.  I understand that return value optimization is a valuable one, I just wonder whether I can rely on it: is it a Pascal 'standard' requirement?

Comment: No, the simplest way is to only use an intermediate if there is the need for one.

Comment: Neither Delphi, nor PascalScript of FreePascal underly a standard. They do things as they see fit. But the latter two usually closely follow the path Delphi uses. Not always, but in basic things, they do. And this is simply the easiest way to implement such a call.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Delphi does **not** restore the original value (it cannot because it does not keep track of values set in the program). I tested that. I would have surprised me if Delphi had done that, actually. So both seem to work identically.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Note that for **simple types** like `Integer`, the passing is different. Then the result is indeed passed in a register after the function ends. Since it doesn't end, because of the exception, a simple variable is not assigned. Your claims are totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it handles result values by reference as implicit first argument. But then this can happen. It could be considered a legal of certain codegeneration/optimization, since it is quite a common way of handling return values.

However what is exactly defined in Object Pascal outside testing what Delphi does is murky territory, since there is only a x86 and x86_64 implementation. And Delphi will return the value in eax, so if you follow that logic this is illegal.

---

added later:

I tested Delphi with structured types, and while it passes a reference, it creates a copy on the stack to pass it.

This could make it hard to optimize code with structured types though, but a modifier/attribute to declare the return type const could fix that if ever needed.

Comment: I tested Delphi with structured types, and while it passes a reference, it creates a copy on the stack to pass it. So that makes it a bug, even if Delphi passes by reference it guards against such cases (at the cost of performance though)

Comment: What "copy on the stack" do you mean? What is the "bug" here?

Comment: Bug in pascalscript.  In the case of a complex/structured returnvalue, FPC and Delphi create a temporary variable of the same type as the return type, and then pass that by reference. After calling the function, the result is copied to its final destination, which, as a whole, avoids the behaviour as shown by PascalScript

Comment: No, Delphi does not do that. Check it. It assigns strings to the Result immediately, no intermediate for strings. As I said, I tested this. It does this for records, indeed. But not for strings.

Comment: It might do something different for automated types, since there is finalization there anyway. I haven't tested that. The original question has been edited, it was integers originally.

Comment: I just wrote a simple test project with three similar setups as the question. The first used integer, the second string, the third a record containing a string. The integer and record versions did not set the new value, because of the exception. The string version did however change the string (before the exception), because that is a direct assingment via the reference. The record version modifies an intermediate record, which is then supposed to be copied to the real target using CopyRect. But the exception prevents that. The integer is returned through EAX, but that is prevented too..